# Barcode iOS plugin : unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

After installing the phonegap plugin [Barcode reader](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner) on iOS, I got the following error:

```
-[CDVbcsViewController setOrientationDelegate:]: 
            unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2fb6a0
```

---

It is worth mentionning that before I could successfully compile the project, I had to do some changes due to a compile error  I was getting in `CDVBarcodeScanner.mm` on line `837`:

```
Use of undeclared identified 'UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait'; 
            did you mean 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait' ?
```

So I removed `Mask` from `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` as suggested.

---

I also have 3 other warnings :

- Semantic issue : `Property 'orientationDelegate' requires method 'setOrientationDelegate' to be defined`
- Semantic issue : `Property 'orientationDelegate' requires method 'orientationDelegate' 
  to be defined`
- Semantic issue: `No previous prototype for function 'compareModuleSize'` (in the file `zxing-all-in-one.cpp`)

any idea what I did wrong ?

Thank you

XCode Version 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I "fixed" the problem by reverting to an older version (as of Jul 23rd, 2012).

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/9f68ff99876711a2b261594b8b5ebf244983e6a9/iOS/BarcodeScanner

The newer versions seem to have compatibility issues with my XCode version.